# Implementing Transport Layer Security in Python - Simple Mail Client

Tags: python, sockets, smtp, ssl

I have an assignment to write a simple mail client, and to connect to a google smtp server using sockets (without using smtp lib). However, issuing a MAIL FROM command to a google smtp server requires ssl or tls, and this is the part I can't figure out. I'm trying to use Python's ssl.wrap_socket() method thusly....

```
# Create socket called clientSocket and establish a TCP connection with mailserver
clientSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
ssl_clientSocket = ssl.wrap_socket(clientSocket) 
ssl_clientSocket.connect((mailserver, port))
```

...which isn't working. I'm pretty sure I need to include the ca_certs and ca_reqs parameters, but I'm not sure. And if this is so, how do I go about obtaining these certificates? Do I have to download openssl and generate one? Anyone with experience with this? Here's the entire code just to be on the safe side.

```
from socket import *
import ssl

msg = "\r\n I love computer networks!"
endmsg = "\r\n.\r\n"

# Choose a mail server (e.g. Google mail server) and call it mailserver
mailserver = "smtp.gmail.com"
port = 587

# Create socket called clientSocket and establish a TCP connection with mailserver
clientSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
ssl_clientSocket = ssl.wrap_socket(clientSocket) 
ssl_clientSocket.connect((mailserver, port))

recv = ssl_clientSocket.recv(1024)
print
print recv

# If the first three numbers of what we receive from the SMTP server are not
# '220', we have a problem
if recv[:3] != '220':
    print '220 reply not received from server.'

# Send HELO command and print server response.
heloCommand = 'HELO Alice\r\n'
ssl_clientSocket.send(heloCommand)
recv1 = ssl_clientSocket.recv(1024)
print recv1

# If the first three numbers of the response from the server are not
# '250', we have a problem
if recv1[:3] != '250':
    print '250 reply not received from server.'

# Send MAIL FROM command and print server response.
mailFromCommand = 'MAIL From: wgimson@gmail.com\r\n'
ssl_clientSocket.send(mailFromCommand)
recv2 = ssl_clientSocket.recv(1024)
print recv2

# If the first three numbers of the response from the server are not
# '250', we have a problem
if recv2[:3] != '250':
    print '250 reply not received from server.'

# Send RCPT TO command and print server response.
rcptToCommand = 'RCPT To: macyali@gmail.com\r\n'
ssl_clientSocket.send(rcptToCommand)
recv3 = ssl_clientSocket.recv(1024)
print recv3

# If the first three numbers of the response from the server are not
# '250', we have a problem
if recv3[:3] != '250':
    print '250 reply not received from server.'

# Send DATA command and print server response.
dataCommand = 'DATA\r\n'
ssl_clientSocket.send(dataCommand)
recv4 = ssl_clientSocket.recv(1024)
print recv4

# If the first three numbers of the response from the server are not
# '250', we have a problem
if recv4[:3] != '250':
    print '250 reply not received from server.'

# Send message data.
ssl_clientSocket.send(msg)

# Message ends with a single period.
ssl_clientSocket.send(endmsg)

# Send QUIT command and get server response.
quitCommand = 'QUIT\r\n'
ssl_clientSocket.send(quitCommand)
recv5 = ssl_clientSocket.recv(I1024)
print recv5

# If the first three numbers of the response from the server are not
# '250', we have a problem
if recv5[:3] != '221':
    print '221 reply not received from server.'
```

Comment: Define "isn't working". Not an adequate problem description.

Comment: I'm getting this error...   
ssl.SSLError: [Errno 185090050] _ssl.c:340: error:0B084002:x509 certificate routines:X509_load_cert_crl_file:system lib

Comment: Ok, so I've downloaded the latest cacerts.pem file, and now I'm getting the error ssl.SSLError: [Errno 1] _ssl.c:504: error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol

Answer (score 2):

You're connecting to port 587, which is the port for STARTTLS. When using SMTPS (ie. wrapping the socket before any other communication), you need to connect to port 465 instead of port 587. If you use STARTTLS, you wrap the socket later, after using the `STARTTLS` command and receiving a `220` response to it. After doing `STARTTLS`, you're supposed to do `HELO` again, since the server is supposed to forget anything that happened before the `STARTTLS`.

In either case, the servers at smtp.google.com ports 465 and 587 still won't return a `250` response to the `MAIL` command, since they require that you are authenticated before you send mail. You'll get a `530` response instead. You'll need to use the `AUTH` command with your gmail.com credentials to authenticate before you can use `MAIL` successfully on those servers.

If you don't want to authenticate, and depending on the details of what you need to do, you could try using port 25 of the server found in gmail.com's MX record. At the moment, the server is gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com and supports STARTTLS.

Comment: You should probably say "When using SMTPS" (instead of "when using SSL"), since you can use TLS with SMTPS too (wrapping the socket before any communication), not just with STARTTLS.

Comment: @Bruno, fixed, thanks! I wasn't quite sure about the correct terminology, many places just use "465 = SSL port" and "587 = STARTTLS port". I was hoping saying "STARTTLS" would somehow magically clarify I wasn't talking about SSL vs. TLS. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
 recv5 = ssl_clientSocket.recv(I1024)
```

has a `I` in the port number, is this causing you the issue? Or have you fixed that part already?