# Sending e-mail manually - Python

Tags: python, email, smtp, protocols

I'm trying to send an email to an SMTP server but I keep getting errors from the server. It says my commands are unrecognized with status codes like 500 and 501.

Here is my script:

```
import socket

server_info = ("smtp.gmx.com", 25)

socket = socket.socket()
socket.connect(server_info)

username = raw_input("Enter your username: ")
password = raw_input("Enter your password: ")
recipient = raw_input("Recipient: ")
data = raw_input("Your message: ")
auth = username + "" + password
auth = auth.encode("base64").replace("\n", "")
socket.send("HELO\r\n")
print "EHLO Response: " + socket.recv(1024)
socket.send("AUTH PLAIN "+auth+"\r\n")
print "AUTH Response: " + socket.recv(1024)
socket.send("MAIL FROM:<"+username+">\r\n")
print "MAIL FROM Response: " + socket.recv(1024)
socket.send("RCPT TO:"+recipient+"\r\n")
print "RCPT TO Response: " + socket.recv(1024)
socket.send("RCPT TO:"+recipient+"\r\n")
print "RCPT TO Response: " + socket.recv(1024)
socket.send("DATA\r\n")
print "DATA Response: " + socket.recv(1024)
socket.send(data + "\r\n.\r\n")
print "RAW DATA Response: " + socket.recv(1024)
socket.send("QUIT\r\n")
print "QUIT Response: " + socket.recv(1024)
print "Done."

socket.close()
```

What is the problem with these command? I wrote them exactly like they should be.
Here is the errors I get from the server:

http://i.gyazo.com/3f5eb3a34cbb0f00510281bccc8d0546.png

P.S I don't want to use smtplib. I would like to send my email manually, for learning purposes

Comment: gmail http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21407750/how-can-i-send-email-using-gmails-smtp-without-using-smtplib

Answer (score 2):

You have a great module to send email messages - **smtplib**

Usage example:

```
import smtplib

SMTP_SERVER = 'smtp.gmail.com'
SMTP_PORT = 587

sender = 'example@gmail.com'
password = "password"
recipient = 'example2@gmail.com'
subject = 'Gmail SMTP Test'
body = 'blah blah blah'


body = "" + body + ""

headers = ["From: " + sender,
           "Subject: " + subject,
           "To: " + recipient,
           "MIME-Version: 1.0",
           "Content-Type: text/html"]
headers = "\r\n".join(headers)

session = smtplib.SMTP(SMTP_SERVER, SMTP_PORT)

session.ehlo()
session.starttls()
session.ehlo()
session.login(sender, password)

session.sendmail(sender, recipient, headers + "\r\n\r\n" + body)
session.quit()
```

**UPD**:
If you want to use SSL:

```
...
session = smtplib.SMTP_SSL_PORT(SMTP_SERVER, SMTP_PORT)
session.ehlo()
session.login(sender, password)

session.sendmail(sender, recipient, headers + "\r\n\r\n" + body)
session.quit()
```

Comment: I don't want to use smtplib. I would like to send my email manually, for learning purposes.

Comment: @DavidLasry, Oh, sorry.

Comment: Could you please help me locate the problem in my script?

Comment: @DavidLasry, I am not strong in sockets, but now will try to do something.

Comment: @DavidLasry, we cant send email through socket(in python) because after  starttls we must do tls negotiation, which we cant do by python. We can  use wrap_socket() from ssl module, but you need certificate file for this method.

Answer (score 0):

You're sending "HELO" to start your SMTP session while you should send "EHLO".

The [SMTP authentication mechanism](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4954) is only available if you're using [extended SMTP.](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1869)
Starting your session with HELO tells the servers you're not using extended SMTP, hence it'll reject all authentication commands.