# Python script to send email using Gmail

Tags: python, ssl, smtp, gmail

I have absolutely zero experience with Python socket programming. I am basically learning as I go. Anyway, my instructor gave us an assignment to create a mail client using the skeleton code provided here: http://www.cs.wm.edu/~dnguyen/cs335/project/emailclient.pdf (NOTE: I do not attend WM.)

We are not allowed to use smtplib. I'm using Gmail to send email for this exercise, and upon further reading, I found that I have to use STARTTLS and then use SSL's wrap_socket(), then send EHLO again. This is the output I am getting and I have no idea what to do with it. I read somewhere on SO that the last 250 line means something as it has no hyphen/dash (-) between 250 and the text.

```
220 mx.google.com ESMTP z15sm36730pdi.6 - gsmtp

250-mx.google.com at your service, [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]
250-SIZE 35882577
250-8BITMIME
250-STARTTLS
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-PIPELINING
250-CHUNKING
250 SMTPUTF8

220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS
```

Below is just part of my code. Since this is an individual assignment, I don't want to post the entire code for others in my class. If you would like to see additional code, please ask.

```
starttls = 'STARTTLS\r\n'
clientSocket.send(starttls)
recv2 = clientSocket.recv(1024)
print recv2

sslClientSocket = ssl.wrap_socket(clientSocket)
sslClientSocket.send(login)
getLogin = sslClientSocket.recv(1024)
print getLogin
sslClientSocket.send(password)
getPass = sslClientSocket.recv(1024)
print getPass

if recv2[:3] != '220':
    print '220 tls reply not received from server.'
```

More code info: At the beginning of the file, I import ssl and base64. I define two variables 'login' and 'password' and used base64.b64encode() to encode those. The rest of the code is based on the skeleton code provided above. I send HELO before and after STARTTLS per this thread: [Connect to SMTP (SSL or TLS) using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12854572/connect-to-smtp-ssl-or-tls-using-python)

How do I read the output to determine what is going on? Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3):

> ...and upon further reading, I found that I have to use STARTTLS ... I read somewhere on SO that the last 250 line means something as it has no hyphen/dash (-) between 250 and the text.

You ask a question about a behavior clearly defined in the standards.
I suggest you read the relevant standards [RFC 2821](http://www.rfc-base.org/txt/rfc-2821.txt) and [RFC3207](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3207.txt) in order to understand the protocols, instead of trying to guess protocol details from some stackoverflow posts. You might also have a look at the implementation of smtplib, even if you are not allowed to use the code directly.